# How to place programmatically a circle drawing in the view with constraints

Tags: swift, xcode

I followed a webinar on how to create a circle for a progress indicator and I coded it and works well but what I cannot find is how to move the constraints of my circle programmatically to shift it from the center of my View to a central lower position (y = center-100). I tried with various ways like ->

.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true

but the command is not working

```
  @IBOutlet weak var CircleView: UIView!
  

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    // Drawing a circle
    
    let center = view.center


    // create track layer
    
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 125, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2*CGFloat.pi - CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
    
    // shape layer below
    
    shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    //shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0

CircleView.layer.addSubview(shapeLayer)
```

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I gave you an example project that shows how to create a custom subclass of UIView that manages a shape layer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw a circle on your view that honors layout constraints, it needs to be in a view.

I suggest creating a custom UIView, adding that as a subview of the view that will draw a circle, and then putting constraints on that custom view.

You can set up a custom subclass of UIView that uses a CAShapeLayer as it's content layer, and updates its path when its bounds changes.

I created a sample UIView class, OvalView, which sets itself up with a CAShapeLayer as the class of its backing layer. When the layer's bounds change, it updates the path in the shape layer to contain a rounded rectangle who's corner radius is 1/2 the shorter dimension of the view's bounds. If the view's bounds are a square, the shape will be a circle. If the view's bounds are rectangular, the shape will be a "lozenge".

I created a sample project demonstrating how to use the OvalView. You can [download it from Github](https://github.com/DuncanMC/OvalView) and try it for yourself.

It uses a storyboard to create a view that contains 2 OvalViews. When you rotate your phone the size of the view changes, so the OvalViews change sizes as well.

The screen looks like this:

[image]

Below is the code for the OvalView:

```
//
//  OvalView.swift
//  CircleViews
//
//  Created by Duncan Champney on 4/10/22.
//
/*  Copyright © 2022 Duncan Champney.
    Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */



import UIKit


/// This class simply fills its bounds with a rounded rectangle. As the view's bounds change, it updates itself so the path fills the bounds.
/// When the layer's bounds change, it updates the path in the shape layer to contain a rounded rectangle who's corner radius is 1/2 the shorter dimension of the view's bounds. If the view's bounds are a square, the shape will be a circle. If the view's bounds are rectangular, the shape will be a "lozenge"
class OvalView: UIView {

    /// A computed property that casts the view's backing layer to type CAShapeLayer for convenience.
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer { return self.layer as! CAShapeLayer }

    /// This is the color used to draw the oval. If you change it, the didSet will change the layer's strokeColor
    public var ovalColor: UIColor = .blue{
        didSet {
            guard let layer = self.layer as? CAShapeLayer else { return }
            layer.strokeColor = ovalColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    /// This declaration causes the  OvalView's backing layer to be a CAShapeLayer
    override class var layerClass : AnyClass {
       return CAShapeLayer.self}

    /// If the view's bounds change, update our layer's path
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            createPath()
        }
    }

    /// When we get added to a view, set up our shape layer's properties.
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = ovalColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
    }

    /// Build the path for our shape layer and install it.
    func createPath() {
        let cornerRaidus = min(bounds.height, bounds.width)
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRaidus)
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I created a new View in the storyboard -> Circleview with the constraints from the bottom up to the 2/3 of my superView. I tried to put my shapelayer and tracklayer in this CircleView but don't find how to do it, in my code I added:                                  @IBOutlet weak var CircleView: UIView!    CircleView.layer.addSubview(shapeLayer) gives me an error can you please tell me what command I should add to add my shapeLayer in my CircleView?

Comment: Edit your question to show the new code you tried at the bottom, tell us the specific line that is giving an error and the exact error messsage.

Comment: I added first and last line in my code. The error I get is on the last line -> Value of type 'CALayer' has no member 'addSubview'. What is weird is that CircleView is of type UIView and when I added previously view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer) this was working. How can I link this storyboard created CircleView with my shapeLayer (the circle)?

Comment: Layers and views are not interchangeable. To follow my suggestion, you will need to add a view that contains a layer, and add constraints to that view.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I created a custom OvalView class and a demo project that uses it as a subview of a larger view. You can download from Github and try it yourself.

Comment: My sample project is meant to point you in the right direction, not serve as a copy/paste solution to your specific problem. You will need to adapt it to your needs.